# Changing column names in dataframe using gsub

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, gsub

I have an atomic vector like:

```
col_names_to_be_changed <- c("PRODUCTIONDATE", "SPEEDRPM", "PERCENTLOADATCURRENTSPEED", sprintf("SENSOR%02d", 1:18))
```

I'd like to have `_` between words, have them all lower case, except first letters of words (following [R Style for dataframes from advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html)). I'd like to have something like this:

```
new_col_names <- c("Production_Date", "Percent_Load_At_Current_Speed", sprintf("Sensor_%02d", 1:18))
```

Assume that my words are limited to this list:

```
list_of_words <- c('production', 'speed', 'percent', 'load', 'at', 'current', 'sensor')
```

I am thinking of an algorithm that uses `gsub`, puts `_` wherever it finds a word from the above list and then Capitalizes the first letter of each word. Although I can do this manually, I'd like to learn how this can be done more beautifully using `gsub`. Thanks.

Comment: You probably don't want `gsub`.  Since you have a dictionary list, you probably will be better off using an extraction function like `regmatches`.  But I have a feeling that package *stringi* (or its wrapper *stringr*) will work best for this because of its vectorization over all arguments.

Comment: you should show more effort `gsub('(?<=^|_)([a-z])', '\\U\\1', gsub(sprintf('(?i)(?<=%s)(?=.{2,})', paste(list_of_words, collapse = '|')), '_', tolower(col_names_to_be_changed), perl = TRUE), perl = TRUE)`

Comment: @rawr that worked perfectly. Can you make that into a solution so other can make use of it in the future? The first `gsub` really does the task that is `gsub(sprintf('(?i)(?<=%s)(?=.{2,})', 
                                               paste(list_of_words, collapse = '|')), 
                                       '_', tolower(col_names_to_be_changed), perl = TRUE)` and then the other `gsub` capitalizes the first letters. Thanks.

Comment: doesnt work for the acronym (RPM changes to Rpm) and without the "followed by at least two letters" part, it will split the "at" in "date" (since "at" is in the list) so it's not a great solution

Comment: It's definitely good enough, far better that I had hoped, and I am not sure if there is any other way to not manually make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the list of words and paste them with a look-behind (`(?<=)`). I added the `(?=.{2,})` because this will also match the "AT" in "DATE" since "AT" is in the list of words, so whatever is in the list of words will need to be followed by 2 or more characters to be split with an underscore.

The second `gsub` just does the capitalization

```
list_of_words <- c('production', 'speed', 'percent', 'load', 'at', 'current', 'sensor')
col_names_to_be_changed <- c("PRODUCTIONDATE", "SPEEDRPM", "PERCENTLOADATCURRENTSPEED", sprintf("SENSOR%02d", 1:18))


(pattern <- sprintf('(?i)(?<=%s)(?=.{2,})', paste(list_of_words, collapse = '|')))
# [1] "(?i)(?<=production|speed|percent|load|at|current|sensor)(?=.{2,})"

(split_words <- gsub(pattern, '_', tolower(col_names_to_be_changed), perl = TRUE))
# [1] "production_date"               "speed_rpm"                     "percent_load_at_current_speed"
# [4] "sensor_01"                     "sensor_02"                     "sensor_03"                    

gsub('(?<=^|_)([a-z])', '\\U\\1', split_words, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "Production_Date"               "Speed_Rpm"                     "Percent_Load_At_Current_Speed"
# [4] "Sensor_01"                     "Sensor_02"                     "Sensor_03"
```

Comment: Is there a way to keep words from a list capital `c("rpm", "egt")`? Though here I do not have `"egt"` but in my data I have it. Or maybe we can convert them back into capital?

Comment: @bikhaab well as a brute-force, you could use a similar approach as above `pat <- sprintf('(?i)(%s)', paste(cap_list, collapse = '|')); gsub(pat, '\\U\\1', tolower(col_names_to_be_changed), perl = TRUE)`